# Azure Data Flow- Source query push down

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

My dataflow job has both source & sink as synapse database.

I have a source query with joins & transformations in the dataflow while extracting data from the synapse database.

As we know, dataflow under the hood will spin up the databricks cluster to execute the dataflow code.

My question here, the source query I am using in the data flow will that be executed on the synapse db/databricks cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data flow requires a compute context, which is Spark. When you use a query in the transformation, that query will get executed from that Spark cluster, which essentially gets pushed down into the database engine for resolution.

Comment: May i know what resolution will happen from database engine.

Comment: The database will return the result set to the call from Spark, which is the result of your query.

Comment: Just a follow-up question to the above, my source query is written as per the Synapse SQL dialect when this query is executed from Data Flow will that be converted to Spark code /Spark SQL and executed against databricks cluster?

Comment: Your query will not get transposed into Spark code. It will be executed as a query against your source database.